# Strategies for data coupling when working with node.js + react server side rendering + flux + mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to find a way to lower the possibilities for mistake when working with three tiers of information. Let me try to explain.

I'm building a web app with:

- Node.js
- mongodb
- react (with server side rendering)
- flux (alt.js)
- browserify

The data flows can be one of these two:

1. User ask for a page -> data helper getting the proper data from the db -> passing to alt.js bootstrap to fill all the stores -> asking react to build the app (renderToString) and components rendering the view -> retuning to the client
2. User updates something -> flux action is sent (calling server with ajax) -> data helper preparing the data to be saved in the db -> saving and returning the result to the client -> store updates the state -> react component updates his view

There are three places that need to know the data structure:

1. The data helper in the server that export the proper data from the data structure and send to the mongodb or gets the data from the db and build the data structure
2. The flux store that updates his state after user action
3. The component that render the view from the state

This means that if I want to change the data structure (even if to change the name of one of the properties) I will have to change it in three places which can be very risky and prone for mistakes.

Is there a way to achieve data coupling in JS?

Comment: In most projects the data is rather static and one of the first things addressed in the design. If your data structure is going to change a lot you could use a factory to display the data dynamically. Another option could be relay.

Comment: It's not going to change a lot, I just want to make it more easy for the developers to maintain and add new features.

Comment: The flux store doesn't need to know the data structure since it is getting a record or set of records. The view would need to know depending on how you want to display the data. Relay is probably the nearest to what you are looking for. The idea with relay seems to be to define the structure at the component level. I haven't tried it yet so don't know how that plays.

Comment: The flux should know the data structure because when the data is changed it need to update the state. Can you give me an example for a relay?

Comment: Relay is another Facebook technology. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html.  Unless there is a requirement to update on the field level a flux store could only need to see record level changes. Therefore the flux store would not need to know the fields.

Comment: Thank you @JanakaStevens I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this somewhat, but for a client-side application only. We considered going with an [immutable datastructure](https://github.com/christianalfoni/immutable-store) solution, of which there are several.

In the end we instead went with a message bus solution, based on [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) to message changed state to all parts of the app. We coupled this with a helper function responsible for updating the state of the datastructure, so that all updates are controlled by that function.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I need. I want a server side + client solution which can be done since both the server and the client are working with javascript. We already working with immutable data structure  and bus solution (flux)

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature you wanted is syntax check, which is one of compiler features. And javascript is not a compile language. So my suggestion is to change a language. For me, I've worked with [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) for a long time, it works fine to me. It is a compile language, and javascript is what it compile to. I think it can fits you needs after you defined your interface.

Comment: This is a valid solution which I rather save for last resort.